# Como eu faço um popup um novo JFrame?

Tags: java, swing

Como eu posso fazer para quando pressionar um `JMenuItem` ele mostrar uma janela onde eu teria de inserir, por exemplo, uma data e selecionar a partir de um par de caixas de seleção?

Resumidamente, Como eu faço um "popup" um novo `JFrame`?

Obrigado pela ajuda!

Answer (score 2):

Verifica se é algo deste género que pretendes:

```
import javax.swing.*;

/**
 * JOptionPane showInputDialog example #1.
 * A simple showInputDialog example.
 * @author alvin alexander, http://alvinalexander.com
 */
public class JOptionPaneShowInputDialogExample1
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    // a jframe here isn't strictly necessary, but it makes the example a little more real
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("InputDialog Example #1");

    // prompt the user to enter their name
    String name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame, "What's your name?");

    // get the user's input. note that if they press Cancel, 'name' will be null
    System.out.printf("The user's name is '%s'.\n", name);
    System.exit(0);
  }
}
```

[image: img]

[Link com mais exemplos](http://alvinalexander.com/java/joptionpane-showinputdialog-examples)

Answer (score 2):

Você pode criar este *popup* usando [**`JDialog`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html). Aparentemente você já utiliza **`JFrame`** e sabe que é possível adicionar componentes nele, o **`JDialog`** trabalha da mesma forma.

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String...args) {

        // A Janela 'principal'
        JFrame jFrame = new JFrame();
        jFrame.setSize(300, 300);
        jFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        // O Janela 'popup' que terá os botões de seleção, data, etc
        JDialog jdialog = new JDialog(jFrame, true);
        jdialog.setSize(200, 200);
        jdialog.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        jdialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        // Adicionando os botões de 'radio' no JDialog da mesma forma que é feita no JFrame
        jdialog.add(new JRadioButton("Vermelho"));
        jdialog.add(new JRadioButton("Verde"));
        jdialog.add(new JRadioButton("Azul"));

        jFrame.setVisible(true);
        jdialog.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

#### Resultado:

<kbd>[image: resultado]</kbd>

E então você pode adicionar os componentes (`JLabel`, `JTextField`, etc) de acordo com a necessidade da sua aplicação.